# Is there a tool to transform a JUnit java class file from Selenium IDE to a test class and object page respecting POM pattern?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-ide

As Selenium uses POM pattern, while Selenium IDE export a java file that not respecting POM pattern, I want to know if there is a tool to make this transformation.

Comment: No. There is no such a tool.

Comment: okay thank you @AlexeyR.